# Matrix type OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, types

I want to write some generic function which operates on single elements of a Opencv 3.1 `cv::Mat` object, for example:

```
template <typename T>
T accumulate(cv::Mat mat){
    T acc=0;
    for(int i=0;i<mat.cols();i++)
        for(int j=0;j<mat.rows();j++)
             acc += mat.at<T>(i,j);
    return acc; 
}
```

The problem is that I've read about [Data Types](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html) and I'm quite confused about how to implement (or calling) such function respecting them.

What I mean is: supposing that `mat` type is `CV_32FC`. It's `accumulate` user responsibility to call it correctly through `accumulate<float>(mat)`. This is a famous source of errors (stack overflow is full of questions because people use the wrong type while calling `at`).

How can I avoid this and automate this process?

Comment: Please be specific, What exactly is the problem with them?

Comment: Give a look to my updated question

Comment: This is a famous source of errors, because its c++. All what I think you can do is to add an `CV_ASSERT` checks to make sure that the type `T` is really that of the `Mat` type, and that is what the opencv folk use to alert the API client for his mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Mat_<T>` template in OpenCV derived from the `Mat` class. You might be able to use `cv::Mat_<T> mat`.

Then you should be able to call `accumulate()` on your `cv::Mat_<float>` for example.

Please see the OpenCV `Mat_` class reference:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/dfc/classcv_1_1Mat__.html#gsc.tab=0